# No visible text on button, but needs text for screen reader?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a WinForm app that has a button with a background image.  There is no text for the button.  It just has a 'refresh' symbol on it.

Since there's no text, a screen reader can't "see" the button to indicate what it is.  When I add text, though, it's over the image and looks terrible.

Is there a way in a WinForm app for a button to have hidden text visible to the screen reader, but not to the user?

Comment: Can you update the question with your XAML code?

Comment: If WPF try AutomationProperties.HelpText, if winforms use AccessibleName/AccessibleDescription

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can use left padding to move the text off screen while retaining the background image. Set it to something high like 100 and the text should vanish without the rest of the button being affected.

Comment: This is not WPF.  It is WinForm. C# code, no XAML.

Comment: Try setting forecolor to color.transparent.  Haven't done it before but it's worth a try.  I've done it with backcolors before.

Comment: dont know why you delete it so fast.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the properties of the button, there is an `Accessibility` section.

You can set the following property: `AccessibilityName`

I tested with a screen reader on windows 10 and it used that field when hovering over a button.

[image: button properties screenshot]

Comment: You're a lifesaver.  Thanks so much!